# How to keep textarea from duplicating text when saved in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea

Sorry i don't really know anything about PHP, what im trying to do is have a options page on my WordPress site where you can enter code in a text area and then it will show up in the  section of my pages and everything is working (probably not right but working) except im trying to have `<style type=\"text/css\"></style>` show up inside the textarea without having to Manually put them there. This is how i have it now but the style tags keep duplicating when i save. eg.`<style type=\"text/css\"></style>` save then it shows `<style type=\"text/css\"></style><style type=\"text/css\"></style>`in the textarea.

```
array(  'name' => 'Header CSS ',
        'desc' => 'Add your own css between the <style> tags.',
        'id' => 'nrg_header_css',
        'type' => 'textarea'),

<textarea name="nrg_header_css" rows=8 style="width: 98%;"><?php echo stripslashes(nrg_get_option_setting('nrg_header_css')); ?><style type=\"text/css\"></style></textarea>
        <br />
        <p class="submit">
         <input name="<?php echo($actname); ?>" type="submit" value="<?php echo($flabel); ?>" />    
         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php echo($actname); ?>" />
        </p>
```

Thanks

Comment: You're looking at the wrong end. You should not put a placeholder into the textarea and save it. Just output the script tags when they are really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<textarea name="nrg_header_css" rows=8 style="width: 98%;">
<?php echo stripslashes(nrg_get_option_setting('nrg_header_css')); ?>
<style type=\"text/css\"></style>
</textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea name="nrg_header_css" rows=8 style="width: 98%;">
<?php
$content = stripslashes(nrg_get_option_setting('nrg_header_css'));
if($content=='')
{
    echo '<style type=\"text/css\"></style>';
}
else
{
    echo $content;
}
?>
</textarea>
```